# How to build dimensions from SCD tables

Tags: ssas, slowly-changing-dimension

Having the foresight to begin collecting data from our production environment several years ago, I have a table with a following structure-

Part
Status
Startdate
Enddate

I can write a relational join, but how do I then go about including this in my project? What should I do in the DSV and in the Dimension relationships?

Comment: Jeff,  I can't remove this since it has an upvoted answer.  It would probably add some value if you clarified the question based on your new/current understanding of the issue.  If it was based on a misunderstanding, you are probably not the first or last person to have that issue!

Comment: In my solution, I currently have a non-changing dimension where I join on the natural key - part number. In the DSV, I link the two tables with a relationship where they are equal. If I want that to be a SCD, I can't specify a complex relationship criteria like part = part and date > startdate and date < enddate. The correct procedure is to use surrogate keys maintained in the ETL process to link the fact table to the appropriate row in the dimension table. When you create the DSV, you simply use the equal relationship like any other dimension.

Answer (score 1):

in the BIDS, open your project and double click on your DSV file, you can right click any where and add a table and then do the rest of steps like adding a relation

look at images

Step 1 [image: Add Table in DSV]
Step 2 [image: Add Relation]

Is that what you meant

Comment: But then how do I create a relationship where the date in the fact table is between two values in the dimension table?

Comment: in your time dimension table, keep a record for every day, from as much years as you need, and have two foreign keys in your fact table, a startdate key and enddate key

Comment: I have that already. My point is, how do you relate the fact saledate to the correct dimension member? If the saledate is 2012-6-21, it needs to relate to the scd dimension where startdate is 6-1-2012 and enddate is 6-30-2012.

Comment: jeff i kept thinking about your issue, but i still don't understand what you want exactly, is it related to Time dimension or how to update an SCD, or something else

Answer (score -1):

The proper technique is to relate the records in your relational tables. If done correctly, you do not need to to treat fact-dimension relationships any differently than non-SCD ones.